# Replace spaces with commas using Regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to replace space with comma for this particular pattern only not all spaces:
"21311 asd"

Input:

```py
["dog,cat ax 21311 asd","131 MAN"]
```

Desired output:

```py
["dog,cat ax 21311,asd","131,MAN"]
```

Code:

```py
input = ["dog,cat ax 21311 asd","131 MAN"]

new_list = []
for i in input:
    word = re.findall(r"\d*\s[a-zA-Z]*" , i)
    new_word = re.sub(word , r"\d*\s[a-zA-Z]*" , i)
    new_list = new_list + new_word
print(new_list)
```

I know this is wrong syntax, but I don't know how to do it using Regex or any other method.

I'm using Python 3 and Jupyter notebook.

Comment: You sure you need RegEx for this? Sounds like something that [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) can do. Also, you should avoid shadowing built-in names like `input`. The reference to the `input` function will be overwritten by your list.

Comment: Actually I didn't ask question properly my bad..I have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now that you clarified your request, assuming the pattern you are interested in is

> *one or more digits followed by a space followed by one or more ASCII letters*

Here is the correct way to do it:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s([a-zA-Z])")
replacement = r"\1,\2"

inp = ["dog,cat ax 21311 asd", "131 MAN"]

out = [re.sub(pattern, replacement, s) for s in inp]

print(out)
```

The [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function accepts references to matching groups in its `repl` argument. We group the digits (1) and the letters (2) and thus replace the substring with those two groups with a comma in between.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
input = ["dog,cat,21311 asd", "131 MAN"]
print([data.replace(' ', ',') for data in input])
```

Comment: Actually, I only want to replace a space with comma for particular pattern only like "1554 NAS" or "78412 abcdef" not all spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `re.sub()` with the wrong argument positions, the correct way is to call it like `re.sub(regex, replace, string)`. Also you are iterating over input incorrectly. That's the right way to do it:

```py
import re
input = ["dog,cat,21311 asd","131 MAN"]

new_list = []
for word in input:
    new_word = re.sub(r" " , ",", word)
    new_list.append(new_word)

print(new_list)
```

Comment: While this is technically correct and an answer to OP question, it _does_ feel a little like cracking a walnut with a sledgehammer. In the same vein, the raw string literal for the space `r" "` seems a little unnecessary.

Comment: please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `re.sub()` and pattern with positive Lookahead and Lookbehind

```
import re
lst = ["dog,cat ax 21311 asd","131 MAN"]

new_list = [re.sub(r"(?<=\d)\s+(?=[a-zA-Z])",",", i) for i in lst]
print(new_list)
```

```
['dog,cat ax 21311,asd', '131,MAN']
```